# couchdb reduce to a matrix

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I have a a couchdb with a series of documents like this

```
{
  "foo" :1,
  "bar" : 2
}
{
  "foo" :3,
  "bar" : 4
}
```

and am trying to create a view that reduces to

```
{
   "ColumnNames" : ["foo","bar"],
   "Values" : [[1,3],[2,4]] 
}
```

but am currently stuck with:

```
function (keys, values, rereduce) {
    var firstPass = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++ ){
        var v = values[i];
        for(var prop in v){
            if(v.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
                if (!firstPass.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                    firstPass[prop] = [];
                }
                var ve = v[prop];
                firstPass[prop].push(ve);
            }
        }
    }
    return firstPass;
}
```

that reduces to

```
{
   "foo" : [[1],[3]],
   "bar" : [[2],[4]]
}
```

and I can't figure out how to get the rest of the way

Answer (score -1):

Good use case for a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to group the data, then once grouped pass  to your results object

```js
const data = [{
    "foo": 1,
    "bar": 2
  },
  {
    "foo": 3,
    "bar": 4
  }
];

const m = new Map()

data.forEach(e => { 
  Object.entries(e).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    !m.has(k) && m.set(k, []);    
     m.get(k).push(v);
  });
});

const res = {
  ColumnNames: [...m.keys()],
  Values: [...m.values()]
}

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important;}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm somewhat at at a loss on how to translate your code into something that would run in a couchdb view

Comment: Can wrap it in a function the same as in your question

Comment: unless you are experimenting with newer query servers this would have to be transpiled and would then be pretty annoying to get into an escaped string.. couchapp would do the last part..

Comment: There's no data collection to iterate over, so I can't see what wrapping it, in a function would accomplish